# Reinitializing datatable and individual filter columns

Tags: datatable

I need to initialize a Datatable and load data when a button is clicked. It works but it's creating a duplicate header under the filter columns. I have tried to destroy the Datatable but still no luck.. Hope someone can help.

I tried checking if the datatable exists then destroying the DT with the following: Also added `destroy:true;`

```js
var table = $('#kt_table_1').DataTable().clear().destroy();
$('#kt_table_1 tbody').empty();
$('#kt_table_1 thead th').empty();
$("thead", table).remove();
$("thead .filter", table).empty();


var KTDatatablesSearchOptionsColumnSearch = function() {

  $.fn.dataTable.Api.register('column().title()', function() {
    return $(this.header()).text().trim();
  });

  var initTable1 = function() {

    if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#kt_table_1')) {
      console.log("yes exists");
    }

    // begin first table
    var table = $('#kt_table_1').DataTable({

      responsive: true,
      select: {
        style: 'multi',
        selector: 'td:first-child .kt-checkable',
      },

      headerCallback: function(thead, data, start, end, display) {
        thead.getElementsByTagName('th')[0].innerHTML = `
                 <label class="kt-checkbox kt-checkbox--single kt-checkbox--solid kt-checkbox--brand">
                 <input type="checkbox" value="" class="kt-group-checkable">
                 <span></span>
                 </label>`;
      },

      buttons: [
        'print',
        'copyHtml5',
        'excelHtml5',
        'csvHtml5',
        'pdfHtml5',
      ],

      // Pagination settings
      dom: `<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>
                <'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-5'i><'col-sm-12 col-md-7 dataTables_pager'lp>>`,
      // read more: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html

      lengthMenu: [5, 10, 25, 50],

      pageLength: 10,

      language: {
        'lengthMenu': 'Display _MENU_',
      },

      searchDelay: 500,
      processing: true,
      serverSide: true,
      destroy: true,
      ajax: {
        url: './demo2/contents/encargos/server.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          // parameters for custom backend script demo
          columnsDef: [
            'RecordID', 'OrderID', 'Country', 'ShipCity', 'CompanyAgent', 'ShipDate', 'Status', 'Type', 'Actions', 'url'
          ],
        },
      },
      columns: [{
          data: 'RecordID'
        },
        {
          data: 'OrderID'
        },
        {
          data: 'Country'
        },
        {
          data: 'ShipCity'
        },
        {
          data: 'CompanyAgent'
        },
        {
          data: 'ShipDate'
        },
        {
          data: 'Status'
        },
        {
          data: 'Type'
        },
        {
          data: 'Actions',
          responsivePriority: -1
        },
      ],

      initComplete: function() {

        var thisTable = this;

        var rowFilter = $('<tr class="filter"></tr>').appendTo($(table.table().header()));

        this.api().columns().every(function() {

          var column = this;
          var input;

          switch (column.title()) {
            case 'Record ID':
            case 'Order ID':
            case 'Ship City':
            case 'Company Agent':
              input = $(`<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm form-filter kt-input" data-col-index="` + column.index() + `"/>`);
              break;

            case 'Country':
              input = $(`<select class="form-control form-control-sm form-filter kt-input" title="Select" data-col-index="` + column.index() + `">
                <option value="">Select</option></select>`);
              column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
                $(input).append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>');
              });
              break;

            case 'Status':
              var status = {
                1: {
                  'title': 'Pending',
                  'class': 'kt-badge--brand'
                },
                2: {
                  'title': 'Delivered',
                  'class': ' kt-badge--danger'
                },
                3: {
                  'title': 'Canceled',
                  'class': ' kt-badge--primary'
                },
                4: {
                  'title': 'Success',
                  'class': ' kt-badge--success'
                },
                5: {
                  'title': 'Info',
                  'class': ' kt-badge--info'
                },
                6: {
                  'title': 'Danger',
                  'class': ' kt-badge--danger'
                },
                7: {
                  'title': 'Warning',
                  'class': ' kt-badge--warning'
                },
              };
              input = $(`<select class="form-control form-control-sm form-filter kt-input" title="Select" data-col-index="` + column.index() + `">
                <option value="">Select</option></select>`);
              column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
                $(input).append('<option value="' + d + '">' + status[d].title + '</option>');
              });
              break;

            case 'Type':
              var status = {
                1: {
                  'title': 'Online',
                  'state': 'danger'
                },
                2: {
                  'title': 'Retail',
                  'state': 'primary'
                },
                3: {
                  'title': 'Direct',
                  'state': 'success'
                },
              };
              input = $(`<select class="form-control form-control-sm form-filter kt-input" title="Select" data-col-index="` + column.index() + `">
                <option value="">Select</option></select>`);
              column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
                $(input).append('<option value="' + d + '">' + status[d].title + '</option>');
              });
              break;

            case 'Ship Date':
              input = $(`
                <div class="input-group date">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm kt-input" readonly placeholder="From" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" id="kt_datepicker_1"
                 data-col-index="` + column.index() + `"/>
                <div class="input-group-append">
                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="la la-calendar-o glyphicon-th"></i></span>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group date">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm kt-input" readonly placeholder="To" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" id="kt_datepicker_2"
                 data-col-index="` + column.index() + `"/>
                <div class="input-group-append">
                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="la la-calendar-o glyphicon-th"></i></span>
                </div>
                </div>`);
              break;

            case 'Actions':
              var search = $(`<button class="btn btn-brand kt-btn btn-sm kt-btn--icon">
                 <span>
                 <i class="la la-search"></i>
                 <span>Search</span>
                 </span>
                </button>`);

              var reset = $(`<button class="btn btn-secondary kt-btn btn-sm kt-btn--icon">
                 <span>
                 <i class="la la-close"></i>
                 <span>Reset</span>
                 </span>
                </button>`);

              $('<th>').append(search).append(reset).appendTo(rowFilter);

              $(search).on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var params = {};
                $(rowFilter).find('.kt-input').each(function() {
                  var i = $(this).data('col-index');
                  if (params[i]) {
                    params[i] += '|' + $(this).val();
                  } else {
                    params[i] = $(this).val();
                  }
                });
                $.each(params, function(i, val) {
                  // apply search params to datatable
                  table.column(i).search(val ? val : '', false, false);
                });
                table.table().draw();
              });

              $(reset).on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(rowFilter).find('.kt-input').each(function(i) {
                  $(this).val('');
                  table.column($(this).data('col-index')).search('', false, false);
                });
                table.table().draw();
              });
              break;
          }

          if (column.title() !== 'Actions') {
            $(input).appendTo($('<th>').appendTo(rowFilter));
          }

        });

        // hide search column for responsive table
        var hideSearchColumnResponsive = function() {
          thisTable.api().columns().every(function() {
            var column = this
            if (column.responsiveHidden()) {
              $(rowFilter).find('th').eq(column.index()).show();
            } else {
              $(rowFilter).find('th').eq(column.index()).hide();
            }
          })
        };

        // init on datatable load
        hideSearchColumnResponsive();
        // recheck on window resize
        window.onresize = hideSearchColumnResponsive;

        $('#kt_datepicker_1,#kt_datepicker_2').datepicker({
          autoclose: true
        });
      },
      columnDefs: [{
          targets: 0,
          orderable: false,
          render: function(data, type, full, meta) {

            return '<label class="kt-checkbox kt-checkbox--single kt-checkbox--solid kt-checkbox--brand"><input type="checkbox" value="' + data + '" class="kt-checkable"><span></span></label>';

          },
        },
        {
          targets: -1,
          title: 'Actions',
          orderable: false,
          render: function(data, type, full, meta) {

            console.log(full);

            var id = full['RecordID'];
            var url = full['url'];

            return `
                 <span class="dropdown">
                 <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon btn-icon-md" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
                 <i class="la la-ellipsis-h"></i>
                 </a>
                 <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                 <a class="dropdown-item" href="` + url + `/edit.php"><i class="la la-edit"></i> Edit Details</a>
                 <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="la la-leaf"></i> Update Status</a>
                 <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="la la-print"></i> Generate Report</a>
                 </div>
                 </span>
                 <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon btn-icon-md" title="View">
                 <i class="la la-edit"></i>
                 </a>`;
          },
        },
        {
          targets: 5,
          width: '150px',
        },
        {
          targets: 6,
          render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
            var status = {
              1: {
                'title': 'Pending',
                'class': 'kt-badge--brand'
              },
              2: {
                'title': 'Delivered',
                'class': ' kt-badge--danger'
              },
              3: {
                'title': 'Canceled',
                'class': ' kt-badge--primary'
              },
              4: {
                'title': 'Success',
                'class': ' kt-badge--success'
              },
              5: {
                'title': 'Info',
                'class': ' kt-badge--info'
              },
              6: {
                'title': 'Danger',
                'class': ' kt-badge--danger'
              },
              7: {
                'title': 'Warning',
                'class': ' kt-badge--warning'
              },
            };
            if (typeof status[data] === 'undefined') {
              return data;
            }
            return '<span class="kt-badge ' + status[data].class + ' kt-badge--inline kt-badge--pill">' + status[data].title + '</span>';
          },
        },
        {
          targets: 7,
          render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
            var status = {
              1: {
                'title': 'Online',
                'state': 'danger'
              },
              2: {
                'title': 'Retail',
                'state': 'primary'
              },
              3: {
                'title': 'Direct',
                'state': 'success'
              },
            };
            if (typeof status[data] === 'undefined') {
              return data;
            }
            return '<span class="kt-badge kt-badge--' + status[data].state + ' kt-badge--dot"></span>&nbsp;' +
              '<span class="kt-font-bold kt-font-' + status[data].state + '">' + status[data].title + '</span>';
          },
        },
        {
          targets: 8,
          orderable: false,
        },
      ],
    });

    table.on('change', '.kt-group-checkable', function() {
      var set = $(this).closest('table').find('td:first-child .kt-checkable');
      var checked = $(this).is(':checked');

      $(set).each(function() {
        if (checked) {
          $(this).prop('checked', true);
          table.rows($(this).closest('tr')).select();
        } else {
          $(this).prop('checked', false);
          table.rows($(this).closest('tr')).deselect();
        }
      });
    });


    $('#export_print').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      table.button(0).trigger();
    });

    $('#export_copy').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      table.button(1).trigger();
    });

    $('#export_excel').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      table.button(2).trigger();
    });

    $('#export_csv').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      table.button(3).trigger();
    });

    $('#export_pdf').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      table.button(4).trigger();
    });

    $('#action_delete').on('click', function(e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      var count = table.rows({
        selected: true
      }).count();

      if (count > 0) { // at-least one checkbox checked

        var ids = [];

        $('.kt-checkable').each(function() {

          if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            ids.push($(this).val());
          }

        });

        var ids_string = ids.toString(); // array to string conversion 

        if (confirm("Eliminar " + ids_string + " ?")) {

          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./demo2/modules/production/encargos/delete_group.php",
            data: {
              data_ids: ids_string
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result) {
              console.log(result);
              table.ajax.reload();
              NotifyPage('Eliminado correctamente', 'danger');
            },
            async: false
          });

        }

      }

    });

  };

  return {

    //main function to initiate the module
    init: function() {
      initTable1();
    },

  };

}();

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  KTDatatablesSearchOptionsColumnSearch.init();
});
```

Comment: Posting hundreds of lines of code will not help people in figuring out what the problem is. Please limit your question to something more specific.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), emphasis on minimal.

Comment: sorry, was my first post. Since then I took a different aproach.. I am stuck now with another issue. I will make a new post. Thanks for you quick response.